# 404 Not Found. Recurso ou local?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Senhores,

Tenho uma webapi cujo end point é usado para retornar informações de um funcionário.

Considerem os dois cenários abaixo :

1. No cenário 1 a URL abaixo é invalida, inexistente. Naturalmente o servidor devolve o 404 (Not Found)

https://sistema.com.br/api/v1/**funcionarios**/1

Obs. funcionários está incorreto.

2. No segundo cenário, a url é valida, o código cai na Action da Controller, se conecta à base procurando pelo funcionário com ID = 1. Porem esse não existe.
   Dai eu preciso informar explicitamente o Status Code para o Response.

   ;

   ```
       try
       {
           var funcionario = await Task.FromResult(new FuncionarioApplication().ObtemFuncionario(id));

           if (funcionario!=null)
           {
               ApiResult.StatusCode = 200;
           }
           else
           {
               ApiResult.StatusCode = 204;
           }

       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           ApiResult.AddError($"Ocorreu uma Exception ao tentar localizar o funcionario. Detalhe : {e.Message} Origem : {e.StackTrace}");
           ApiResult.StatusCode = 400;
       }
       return base.StatusCode(Result.StatusCode, ApiResult.GetResult());
   ```

Aqui estou retornando o codigo 204 - No Content

Comment: 400 requisição invalida ou 416 Solicitada de Faixa Não Satisfatória

Comment: se o produto não existe é 404, "não existe", não foi uma requisição inválida

Comment: Complementei a pergunta com mais detalhes.

Comment: 404 é perfeitamente aceitável no seu `else`, já que é justamente isso, algo não encontrado. 204 é "encontrado" (ou processado), mas que não vai apresentar nada na resposta. Um exemplo disto é uma ação post/put para salvar algo que não precisaria de uma "confirmação" completa, algo como salvar rascunhos automáticos de mensagens que estão sendo editadas.Outra coisa, `400 Bad request` não faz sentido, ele seria um problema se fosse falha no REQUEST e não no lado do servidor, se ocorreu uma exception é porque tem algo muito errado, status `500 Internal Server Error` seria mais apropriado.

Comment: Show..vlw brother

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404), o erro 404 é um código de resposta HTTP que indica que o cliente pôde comunicar com o servidor, mas ou o servidor não pôde encontrar o que foi pedido, ou foi configurado para não cumprir o pedido e não revelar a razão, ou a página não existe mais. Eles não devem ser confundidos com outros erros nos quais uma conexão para o servidor de destino não pôde ser feita.

Você deve sim retornar o erro 404.

Lembre-se os códigos de erro começados em 4 (404, 402, 410, ...) são códigos de erros causados pelo cliente HTTP.